# Trying to SELECT row by long list of composite primary keys in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

This is my query using code found perusing this site:

```
query="""SELECT Family
           FROM Table2
     INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.idSequence=Table2.idSequence
     WHERE (Table1.Chromosome, Table1.hg19_coordinate) IN ({seq})
""".format(seq=','.join(['?']*len(matchIds_list)))
```

`matchIds_list` is a list of tuples in (?,?) format.

It works if I just ask for one condition (ie just `Table1.Chromosome` as oppose to both `Chromosome` and `hg_coordinate`) and `matchIds_list` is just a simple list of single values, but I don't know how to get it to work with a composite key or both columns.

Comment: Building SQL like this is discouraged. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: He's using "?" which is used to parameterize a query. That's the *correct* way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running SQLite 3.7.17, I'd recommend to just use a temporary table.

Create and populate your temporary table.

```
cursor.executescript("""
    CREATE TEMP TABLE control_list (
        Chromosome TEXT NOT NULL,
        hg19_coordinate TEXT NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE INDEX control_list_idx ON control_list (Chromosome, hg19_coordinate);
""")

cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO control_list (Chromosome, hg19_coordinate)
    VALUES (?, ?)
""", matchIds_list)
```

Just constrain your query to the control list temporary table.

```sql
SELECT Family
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
    ON Table1.idSequence = Table2.idSequence

-- Constrain to control_list.
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM control_list
        WHERE control_list.Chromosome = Table1.Chromosome
            AND control_list.hg19_coordinate = Table1.hg19_coordinate
    )
```

And finally perform your query (there's no need to format this one).

```
cursor.execute(query)

# Remove the temporary table since we're done with it.
cursor.execute("""
    DROP TABLE control_list;
""")
```

---

Short Query (requires SQLite 3.15): You actually almost had it. You need to make the `IN ({seq})` a subquery
expression.

```sql
SELECT Family
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
    ON Table1.idSequence = Table2.idSequence
WHERE (Table1.Chromosome, Table1.hg19_coordinate) IN (VALUES {seq});
```

Long Query (requires SQLite 3.8.3): It looks a little complicated, but it's pretty straight forward. Put your
control list into a sub-select, and then constrain that main select by the control
list.

```sql
SELECT Family
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
    ON Table1.idSequence = Table2.idSequence

-- Constrain to control_list.
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                -- Name the columns (must match order in tuples).
                "" AS Chromosome,
                ":1" AS hg19_coordinate
            FROM (
                -- Get control list.
                VALUES {seq}
            ) AS control_values
        ) AS control_list
        -- Constrain Table1 to control_list.
        WHERE control_list.Chromosome = Table1.Chromosome
            AND control_list.hg19_coordinate = Table1.hg19_coordinate
    )
```

Regardless of which query you use, when formatting the SQL replace `{seq}` with `(?,?)` for each compsite
key instead of just `?`.

```
query = " ... ".format(seq=','.join(['(?,?)']*len(matchIds_list)))
```

And finally flatten `matchIds_list` when you execute the query because it is a list of tuples.

```
import itertools
cursor.execute(query, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matchIds_list)))
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply! I was trying to test a simpler query and didn't understand why even this didn't work `sqlite> SELECT Family FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.idSequence=Table2.idSequence WHERE (Table1.Chromosome, Table1.hg19_coordinate) IN (('1','102568923'), ('1','12333567'));`

Comment: I tried the code you provided and it is giving me an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nchuang/MyTools/test_database/test_database.py", line 183, in <module>
    c.execute(query, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matchIds_list)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error`. Just saw your edit. I will check it.

Comment: I tried both long and short query. For my short query I also updated my `join` to include `'(?,?)` and flattened the list. It gives me a `sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Comment: @nchuang Do you know what version of SQLite you're running? You can query it with `SELECT sqlite_version()`.

Comment: the sqlite3 library I'm using is 3.7.17. Btw adding `VALUES` made my first comment work! So the short query you gave me should definitely work. I don't understand what's different here.

Comment: meaning I just need to get the latest sqlite3 installed? It is right now I think 100 and theoretically I would like to recycle the syntax for up to 1000 items.

Comment: @nchuang See my update. I think I have a solution that will work for your version.

Comment: temporary table appears to work! I will need to just test it and maybe alter it a bit. I have asked our IT to also update the sqlite/sqlite3/pysqlite but still trying to figure that out. Will use this for now. Thanks for all the patience and help!